# Can DeepSort be made to track objects beside people?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, object-detection, yolo

As far as my understanding goes, the model used for feature extraction in [DeepSort](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort) is specified as the first argument of the function `create_box_encoder` in the file [`tools/generate_detections.py`](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort/blob/master/tools/generate_detections.py):

```
def create_box_encoder(model_filename, input_name="images",
                       output_name="features", batch_size=32):
    image_encoder = ImageEncoder(model_filename, input_name, output_name)
    image_shape = image_encoder.image_shape

    def encoder(image, boxes):
        image_patches = []
        for box in boxes:
            patch = extract_image_patch(image, box, image_shape[:2])
            if patch is None:
                print("WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: %s." % str(box))
                patch = np.random.uniform(
                    0., 255., image_shape).astype(np.uint8)
            image_patches.append(patch)
        image_patches = np.asarray(image_patches)
        return image_encoder(image_patches, batch_size)

    return encoder
```

In the same file, the default value of the argument `model_filename` is specified under the `parse_args()` function to be `resources/networks/mars-small128.pb`, which appears to be a model for person re-identification.

Can a model for re-identifying objects other than people (and from multiple classes, such as cars, birds, trucks, etc) be used instead in DeepSort? If so, does DeepSort provide any means for training such models?

My initial understanding was that DeepSort would be able to track all classes recognized by a trained YOLO model. I didn't know that a stand-alone feature extractor was required.